# Using R to process CSV to evaluate if ((ColA != ColB) with consideration for ColC

Tags: r, csv, string-comparison

I'm trying to achieve a simple string comparison across two columns. Sample of (mocked up) data:

```
EMPLID,From_DeptCode,FromDept,To_DeptCode,To_Dept,TransactionTypeCode,TransactionType,EffectiveDate,ChangeType
0239583290,21,Sales,43,CustomerService,10,Promotion,12/12/2012
1230495829,21,Sales,21,Sales,10,Promotion,9/1/2013
4059503918,93,Operations,93,Operations,10,Demotion,11/18/2014
3040593021,19,Headquarters,23,International,11,Reorg,12/13/2011
7029406920,15,Marketing,84,Development,19,Reassignment,01/05/2010
2039052819,19,Headquarters,19,Headquarters,10,Promotion,4/15/2015
```

The logic I want to use is:

```
If From_DeptCode = To_DeptCode 
      then ChangeType="No Change" 
ElseIf From_DeptCode != To_DeptCode AND TransactionType = "Reorg" 
      then ChangeType="Reorg"
Else ChangeType="Transfer"
```

So my output would look like:

```
EMPLID,From_DeptCode,FromDept,To_DeptCode,To_Dept,TransactionTypeCode,TransactionType,EffectiveDate,ChangeType
0239583290,21,Sales,43,CustomerService,10,Promotion,12/12/2012,Transfer
1230495829,21,Sales,21,Sales,10,Promotion,9/1/2013,No Change
4059503918,93,Operations,93,Operations,10,Demotion,11/18/2014,No Change
3040593021,19,Headquarters,23,International,11,Reorg,12/13/2011,Reorg
7029406920,15,Marketing,84,Development,19,Reassignment,01/05/2010,Transfer
2039052819,19,Headquarters,19,Headquarters,10,Promotion,4/15/2015,No Change
```

Here's what I know so far:

```
transfers <- read.csv(file="Transfers.csv", head=TRUE,
    sep=",",colClasses=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Date",NA))
```

at this point, I would, I assume, implement my logic:

```
If From_DeptCode = To_DeptCode 
      then ChangeType="No Change" 
ElseIf From_DeptCode != To_DeptCode AND TransactionType = "Reorg" 
      then ChangeType="Reorg"
Else ChangeType="Transfer"
```

I assume that here I'd write out my new csv
    write.csv(transfers, file = "transfersprocessed.csv", row.names = FALSE)

Any advice on getting the rest of the way there?

## Update:

Per answer from @josilber, I ran the following code:

```
transfers <- read.csv(file="Transfers.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",", colClasses=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Date",NA))

dat$ChangeType <- ifelse(dat$From_DeptCode == dat$To_DeptCode, "No Change",ifelse(dat$TransactionType == "Reorg", "Reorg", "Transfer"))

View(transfers)
```

On the following data:

```
EMPLID,From_DeptCode,FromDept,To_DeptCode,To_Dept,TransactionTypeCode,TransactionType,EffectiveDate,ChangeType
0239583290,21,Sales,43,CustomerService,10,Promotion,12/12/2012
1230495829,21,Sales,21,Sales,10,Promotion,9/1/2013
4059503918,93,Operations,93,Operations,10,Demotion,11/18/2014
3040593021,19,Headquarters,23,International,11,Reorg,12/13/2011
7029406920,15,Marketing,84,Development,19,Reassignment,01/05/2010
2039052819,19,Headquarters,19,Headquarters,10,Promotion,4/15/2015
```

And the ChangeType variable remained "NA".

Is the nested ifelse statement syntax correct? Any idea why the ChangeType isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a nested `ifelse` statement:

```
dat$ChangeType <- ifelse(dat$From_DeptCode == dat$To_DeptCode, "No Change",
                         ifelse(dat$TransactionType == "Reorg", "Reorg", "Transfer"))
dat
#       EMPLID From_DeptCode     FromDept To_DeptCode         To_Dept TransactionTypeCode
# 1  239583290            21        Sales          43 CustomerService                  10
# 2 1230495829            21        Sales          21           Sales                  10
# 3 4059503918            93   Operations          93      Operations                  10
# 4 3040593021            19 Headquarters          23   International                  11
# 5 7029406920            15    Marketing          84     Development                  19
# 6 2039052819            19 Headquarters          19    Headquarters                  10
#   TransactionType EffectiveDate ChangeType
# 1       Promotion    12/12/2012   Transfer
# 2       Promotion      9/1/2013  No Change
# 3        Demotion    11/18/2014  No Change
# 4           Reorg    12/13/2011      Reorg
# 5    Reassignment    01/05/2010   Transfer
# 6       Promotion     4/15/2015  No Change
```

The `ifelse` is passed a vector of TRUE/FALSE values as its first argument, using the second argument for the TRUE cases and using the third argument for the FALSE cases. For your false cases you actually want to run another `ifelse`, which is why the logic is nested here.

Note that for large data frames this will be a good deal quicker than looping through your data and doing the nested if statement one row at a time.

Comment: Nice solution. It's good to see how R attempts vectorization automatically. In this case, there's no need to tell R which row to look into. Awesome!

Comment: What if instead of printing "no change" where dat$From_DeptCode == dat$To_DeptCode, I wanted it to pass or not print the line at all. Would I still use this format?

Comment: @user1694958 this could be accomplished by first generating the ChangeType variable and the subsetting based on the value of the variable (e.g. something like `dat2 <- subset(dat, ChangeType != "No Change")`).

Comment: @user1694958 your code didn't make it into the comment. Anyhow it sounds like you're asking a new question now (how to subset your dataset based on some condition). On Stack Overflow it's better to ask this as a separate question instead of chaining it on to an existing on.

Comment: @josilber, your suggestion with the nested ifelse statement didn't work. The ChangeType code remains NA. How do I post my code and exact data on here without logging it as an answer? Character limits on contents.

Comment: @user1694958 I would suggest editing your question with a data sample. If you have a data frame called `dat`, you could edit the question to add `dput(head(dat))`.