# Using R Nested IfElse statements to compare two variable strings

Tags: r, string, csv, if-statement, printing

Sample Input Data (stored in csv in working directory):

```
EMPLID,From_DeptCode,FromDept,To_DeptCode,To_Dept,TransactionTypeCode,TransactionType,EffectiveDate,ChangeType
0239583290,21,Sales,43,CustomerService,10,Promotion,12/12/2012
1230495829,21,Sales,21,Sales,10,Promotion,9/1/2013
4059503918,93,Operations,93,Operations,13,Demotion,11/18/2014
3040593021,19,Headquarters,23,International,11,Reorg,12/13/2011
7029406920,15,Marketing,84,Development,19,Reassignment,1/5/2010
2039052819,19,Headquarters,19,Headquarters,10,Promotion,4/15/2015
```

Code:

```
Transfers <- read.csv(file="Transfers.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",",colClasses=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Date",NA))

Transfers$ChangeType <- ifelse(Transfers$From_DeptCode == Transfers$To_DeptCode, "No Change", ifelse(Transfers$TransactionType == "Reorg", "Reorg", "Transfer")) 

Transfers2 <- subset(Transfers, ChangeType != "No Change")

print(Transfers2)
```

Expected Output:

```
EMPLID,From_DeptCode,FromDept,To_DeptCode,To_Dept,TransactionTypeCode,TransactionType,EffectiveDate,ChangeType
0239583290,21,Sales,43,CustomerService,10,Promotion,12/12/2012,Transfer
3040593021,19,Headquarters,23,International,11,Reorg,12/13/2011,Reorg
7029406920,15,Marketing,84,Development,19,Reassignment,1/5/2010,Transfer
```

Actual:

```
> print(Transfers2)
Error in print(Transfers2) : object 'Transfers2' not found
```

At a loss for why this is occurring.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I copied your sample input data into a `Transfers.csv` file, executed your lines and everything works.

Comment: If you get the message that "Transfers2 is not found", that means there was an error on a earlier line of code. As far as i can tell your code to read the csv files doesn't match the sample data you've posted.

Comment: @MrFlick What in my code makes you think it you see that doesn't match the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using R to process CSV to evaluate if ((ColA != ColB) with consideration for ColC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243992/using-r-to-process-csv-to-evaluate-if-cola-colb-with-consideration-for-col)

Answer (score -1):

So I found my issue..

In order to get my code to work, I had to place my cursor at the end of the line of each block of code and run them individually in order.

I was skipping to the bottom of the script and putting my cursor below the last line of code and running it and getting the error.

Why is it necessary for me to run each block of code one at a time with my cursor in the block itself?

Comment: This is not the answer.